# How do I fix my navbar to have a profile with image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, profile

I just needed help with something, how do I make it for my nav bar to have an image in the profile image?

Image for how I would like it to look:
[Image for how I would like it to look (also to make it more clear than vague).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEKIy.png)

```css
.navbar__link {
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}


}
// you don't need to add class to a tag, it can be selected by following way
.navbar>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  // make the header take all space of body
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  // make navbar take all space that remains after the logo
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  // make the navbar move left side else it will not be in complete middlle
  transform: translate(-100px);
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.loading-screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
.loading-bar {
  width: 130px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 22px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.loading-bar::before {
  content: '';
  width: 68px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -34px;
  animation: blackbar 1.5s infinite ease;
}
@keyframes blackbar {
  50% {
    left: 96px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="handlePageLoaded()">
  <header>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
      <a href="/"><img width='200' height='50' src='Icons/Seencast home.png' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar" style="justify-content: center;">
      <a href="discovery.html" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">whatshot</span>
      </a>
      <a href="profile.html" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">person_outline</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Loading Screen -->

    <div class="loading-screen">
      <div class="loading-animation">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="90px" height="90px" viewBox="0 0 90 90" enable-background="new 0 0 90 90" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="90" height="90" x="0" y="0"
                xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFoAAABaAQAAAAAQ03yvAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
            AAB6JQAAgIMAAPn/AACA6QAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF2+SX8VGAAAAAmJLR0QAAd2KE6QAAAAJcEhZ
            cwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfkBwsBJxoCRYkNAAAAmElEQVQ4y2P4jwAHGEY5w5zzhx2J
            8xPO3n+A4TMq5/CP2vYPFfZMzCCO5XOb4vPf54Bkfv6veT/n9/3/d0CcP3Y15+f+ng/h/OdjOCAL
            5NyzB3GO1Z//+3v+D3l+EOcZmPP4/mME5/n9zyDOc/vnf3/ffz4fxPl+3u753d/nn8/9PP8Awwf5
            Az9kf38oiOE/PBjCbZRDNw4Awv38T7O+5eEAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMjAtMDctMTFU
            MDE6Mzk6MjYrMDM6MDDkTb6MAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDIwLTA3LTExVDAxOjM5OjI2
            KzAzOjAwlRAGMAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
            </svg>
        <div class="loading-bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>

  <script>
    window.onload = () => {
      const loader = document.querySelector('.loading-screen');
      loader.style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</body>


<script>
  /* Loading Script */
  window.onload = () => {
    const loader = document.querySelector('.loading-screen');
    loader.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>

</body>
```

UPDATES will go under here, will be updated every 10 minutes!

ex: [UPDATE 1] EXAMPLE

real: [UPDATE 1] Nothing so far :/.

[UPDATE 2] Nothing so far :/.

Comment: You are asking to add an image on the upper right corner as "profile image", right?

Comment: Yes, but through file explorer

Comment: Are you about to getting a software into production or do you want to try something out?